# Handling Multiple Buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have an activity that is a full screen of 25 buttons. I was wondering if there was a more efficent was to create listeners for them so that they change colour when clicked instead of:
    `Button buttonA1;
    Button buttonA2;
    Button buttonA3;
    ...
    buttonA1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA1);
    buttonA2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA2);
    buttonA3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA3);
    ...`

and then adding a listener for each...

Is it possible to condense all this into considerably less lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set in your XML file the android:onClick for each button.

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Then in your MainActivity you can use something like.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 //Handle the buttons
 public void onClick(View v) {
 switch(v.getId())
 {
 case R.id.button_a_id:
 // handle button A click;
 break;
 case R.id.button_b_id:
 // handle button B click;
 break;
 default:
 throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
   }
      }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I check which button is pressed in the onClick method?

Comment: I have edited my answer if this is what you need please accept my answer :) Happy coding!

Comment: No problem you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In xml file, you can implement OnClickListener for button like this :

```
...
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="myMethod" />
```

Then, in your java file

```
public void myMethod(View v) {
// does something very interesting
}
```